# How to Track custom events of Nodejs Onsend Outlook Add-in using Application Insights?

Tags: node.js, outlook-addin, azure-application-insights, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I want to track custom events of my nodejs event based(Onsend) Outlook Add-in using Azure Application Insights. I have tried using the "**applicationinsights@3.0.0-beta**" SDK in my event based add-in but I think, I am unable to fetch the results because imports aren't supported in JS according to the Documentation:

[Snip from the Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSTnm.png)

This is the Official Documentation link :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch

Is there a way for me to achieve the integration of application insights to this Add-in?

I tried the following code in a basic Nodejs app and it worked fine:

```
let appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup("[CONNECTION_STRING]").setAutoCollectConsole(true).start();
let client = appInsights.defaultClient;
client.trackEvent({name: "my custom event", properties: {customProperty: "custom property value"}});
```

But, I suspect the fact that because imports aren't supported according to the Documentation, I am unable to accomplish my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the documentation is correct. Imports are not supported with launch events. However, you may want to look into using a module bundler, like webpack, to bundle the resources to be used from the JavaScript file that implements your launch events. That may work.